# KendoGrid filter with kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate and customized kendoGridCellTemplate

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to filter date in a `KendoGrid` column, it works when the default template from the documentation is used with `field="someval"`. But i want to customize the `someVal` with a pipe and then have the ability to filter as well.

#### Works

```
<kendo-grid-column title="Send Time"
                         field="sendTime"
                         filter="date">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

#### Does not work

```
<kendo-grid-column title="SendTime">
            <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate
                         let-dataItem>
                  {{dataItem.sendTime| mytimePipe}}
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate
                         let-filter
                         let-column="column"
                         let-filterService="filterService">
                  <app-date-range-filter [field]="column.field"
                                         [filter]="filter"
                                         [filterService]="filterService">
                  </app-date-range-filter>
            </ng-template>
      </kendo-grid-column>
```

I have managed to reproduce this issue here in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egjl7e).

Am i missing something or doing this incorrectly ? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

So after an hour, I managed to get it working. I did not know that we can provide `field="x"` while still using `kendoGridCellTemplate` with a `pipe` or whatsoever.

I used [this component](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/reusable-filter/#toc-filter-menu-with-popup) with some more added ability on top of it.

[image]

And this is how it is supposed to look in your markup

<

```
kendo-grid-column title="Created Time"
                     field="createdTime">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate
                 let-dataItem>
      {{dataItem.createdTime | timeZonePipe }}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate
                 let-filter
                 let-column="column"
                 let-filterService="filterService">
      <app-date-range-filter [field]="column.field"
                             [filter]="filter"
                             [filterService]="filterService">
      </app-date-range-filter>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
```